# Show Hide, Toggle, Touch, Hover Buttons Pure CSS

Tags: css, button, toggle, hide, show

I am making this show hide / circles in wordpress, which are social icons and special links on the page itself.

On desktops it works as expected, however on mobile resolutions:

- Instead of *hover*, those circles should work on *tap*, and be able to close them too, like a toggle switch
- The circle sub-menus should close as soon as you tap somewhere else on the screen, as well as when scrolling/dragging up/down along the screen

I'm loading this menu only for touch devices, but for the moment the hover effects are added for safety.

- A js fiddle can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/js2020/58x4200u)
- And a code snippet bellow:

```css
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction {
  top: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 22;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact {
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 22;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social {
  top: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 22;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .first_circle {
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-top-location-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  z-index: 3;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .second_circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-location-ra.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .third_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-location-reva.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .first_circle {
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-contact-111-icon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  z-index: 3;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .second_circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-email-contact-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .third_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-mob-contact-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .first_circle {
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-top-social-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  z-index: 3;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .second_circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(/images/twitter.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .third_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/facebook.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .fourth_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/youtube.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle:hover .second_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle:hover .second_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover .second_circle {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  right: 45px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle:hover .third_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle:hover .third_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover .third_circle {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  right: 90px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover .fourth_circle {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  right: 135px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle:hover,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle:hover,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 155px;
}
```

```html
<div align='center' id='mobilemenu2015new2-contact'>
  <div class='contener_circle'>
    <div class='circle first_circle'></div>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle second_circle'></div>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle third_circle'></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div align='center' id='mobilemenu2015new2-locaction'>
  <div class='contener_circle'>
    <div class='circle first_circle'></div>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle second_circle'></div>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle third_circle'></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div align='center' id='mobilemenu2015new2-social'>
  <div class='contener_circle'>
    <div class='circle first_circle'></div>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle second_circle'></div>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle third_circle'></div>
    </a>
    <a href='#'>
      <div class='circle fourth_circle'></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've altered the markup & css a bit, I think it makes more sense now and its a better semantic approach to it:

- basically when the checkbox is `:checked` the adjacent div can be triggered to show or hide its contents, depending on the status of the checkbox;
- you can hide the `input[type='checkbox']` and use a `<label>` or a different `<tag>` to chain up with the next adjacent `<div>` or `<tag>` that holds this submenu, for example like bellow:

---

```
input[type='checkbox'] + label + .submenu-container{
 /*hide the submenu here*/
     display: none;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label + .submenu-container{
     /*show the submenu here*/
     display: block;
}
```

---

However if you need that specific markup, you can look on what I've done with those checkboxes and follow my approach if 
its required.

As I said before, this is the max thing you can make with only css and html, basicaly hide and show submenus, and thats about it.

If you need to hide the menu when you scroll or tap on something different on the screen, you're gonna need some basic js to do it.

---

- Check out the **NON** js-demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/k213om2e/1/)**
- Check out the **JS**-demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldb9rcg8/1/)**
- or the snippet bellow

```css
/*some default styling*/

.toggle-submenu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.mobile-social-menu li,
.mobile-social-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact {
  top: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  z-index: 22;
}
.mobile-social-menu > ul {
  /*this will add some space between menus to the bottom*/
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.mobile-social-menu a,
.toggle-submenu {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mobile-social-menu > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
.mobile-social-menu > ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.mobile-social-menu > ul > li > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  /*some animations for submenu children*/
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  right: -30px;
}
/*now animate each children li, so that theyll appear as if sliding one beneath the other
you can remove this if its not required*/

.mobile-social-menu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(1) {
  right: -90px;
}
.mobile-social-menu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: -60px;
}
.mobile-social-menu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) {
  right: -30px;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label + ul {
  /*this will trigger the submenu to hide*/
  /*hide the submenu initially*/
  opacity: 0;
  left: -150px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label + ul {
  /*this will trigger the submenu to show*/
  /*show it hen the checkbox is checked*/
  opacity: 1;
  left: -180px;
  visibility: visible;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label + ul > li {
  /*some animations for submenu children*/
  right: 0;
}
/*OLD STUFF*/

#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .circle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .first_circle {
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-top-location-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  z-index: 3;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .second_circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-location-ra.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .third_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-location-reva.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .first_circle {
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-contact-111-icon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  z-index: 3;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .second_circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-email-contact-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .third_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-mob-contact-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .first_circle {
  background-image: url(/images/mobile-top-social-ico.png);
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  z-index: 3;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .second_circle {
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url(/images/twitter.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .third_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/facebook.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .fourth_circle {
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(/images/youtube.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle:hover .second_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle:hover .second_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover .second_circle {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  right: 45px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle:hover .third_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle:hover .third_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover .third_circle {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  right: 90px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover .fourth_circle {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #999999;
  right: 135px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
#mobilemenu2015new2-contact .contener_circle:hover,
#mobilemenu2015new2-locaction .contener_circle:hover,
#mobilemenu2015new2-social .contener_circle:hover {
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 155px;
}
```

```html
<div class='mobile-social-menu' id='mobilemenu2015new2-contact'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!--The input id & the label for must be the same and unique from the other menus-->
      <input id='first-submenu' type='checkbox' class='toggle-submenu-checkbox' />
      <label for='first-submenu' class='toggle-submenu'></label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!--The input id & the label for must be the same and unique from the other menus-->
      <input id='second-submenu' type='checkbox' class='toggle-submenu-checkbox' />
      <label for='second-submenu' class='toggle-submenu'></label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!--The input id & the label for must be the same and unique from the other menus-->
      <input id='third-submenu' type='checkbox' class='toggle-submenu-checkbox' />
      <label for='third-submenu' class='toggle-submenu'></label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            <!--social icon goes here-->
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<!--OLD STUFF
<div align='center' id='mobilemenu2015new2-contact'>
  <div class='contener_circle'>
    <div class='circle first_circle'></div>
    <a   href='#'>
    <div class='circle second_circle'> </div>
    </a><a  href='#'>
    <div class='circle third_circle'> </div>
    </a></div>
</div>
<div align='center' id='mobilemenu2015new2-locaction'>
  <div class='contener_circle'>
    <div class='circle first_circle'></div>
    <a href='#'>
    <div class='circle second_circle'> </div>
    </a><a href='#'>
    <div class='circle third_circle'> </div>
    </a></div>
</div>
<div align='center'   id='mobilemenu2015new2-social'>
  <div class='contener_circle'>
    <div class='circle first_circle'></div>
    <a href='#' >
    <div class='circle second_circle'> </div>
    </a><a href='#'  >
    <div class='circle third_circle'> </div>
    </a><a href='#'  >
    <div class='circle fourth_circle'> </div>
    </a> </div>
</div>-->
```